# How to execute / import Selenium Web Driver Tests written in Java to Selenium IDE

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I tried to get answer to this question using the Selenium documentation and also stack exchange search and google search but I couldn't find an answer.

I am new to Selenium so there might be a simple answer to it.

We have developed some test cases using Eclipse IDE and JUnit with Selenium. We would like to execute these test cases using Selenium IDE. The scenario is that a techy QA analyst used Java to create the test cases. Now, we need other QA / functional team to be able to execute these tests using their browsers. How do we accomplish this using Selenium tool set?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can only convert IDE code to Java. You can't import Java code to IDE.

Comment: So, what are our options to address the scenario mentioned above?

Comment: I believe there are none. There are no options to change java code suitable for IDE.

Comment: Thanks, I meant should we use Selenium Grid or some other way to host these test on a server and let QA team execute from their browsers?

Comment: Yes, that would be posssible.

Comment: Is it possible for someone to provide guidance (high level steps) on how to accomplish this setup (Java test development, setting up grid and enabling QA team to execute from their browsers)

Comment: Create a new question so that people will get attention on that.